Issue with androidx.navigation library and slash sign
Issue description:
When I try to create custom navigation type and navigate to certain destination in my NavGraph, I get error, which states, that this certain destination cannot be found in the graph. After checking, some of items on list of adressess have street name for example Green Street 1 which doesn't cause any issue, but adressess with street name as Green Street 1/3 do. I suppose it might be related to the androidx.navigation library itself, as under the hood, navigation in this library works with URLS, which contain slashes between variables.
Actual outcome:
Application crashes after navigating to address with slash "/" sign
Expected outcome:
Application doesn't crash after navigation to adressess both with and without "/" sign in it.
Code:
@Serializable
data class Address(
    val city: String?,
    val companyId: Int,
    val country: String?,
    val gpsCoordinates: String?,
    val id: Int,
    val pointName: String? = null,
    val pointType: String,
    val postalCode: String?,
    val street: String?
)


val AddressType = object : NavType<Address?>(isNullableAllowed = true) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): Address? {
        return bundle.getString(key)?.takeIf { it != "null" }
            ?.let { Json.decodeFromString<Address>(it) }
    }

    override fun parseValue(value: String): Address? {
        return if (value == "null") null else Json.decodeFromString<Address>(value)
    }

    override fun serializeAsValue(value: Address?): String {
        return Json.encodeToString(value)
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: Address?) {
        bundle.putString(key, Json.encodeToString(value))
    }
}

In my NavGraph everything looks correct, as I am able to navigate to destinations without street name containing "/" sign.

That is a rather complex value to be passing as a navigation argument. Have you considered passing an identifier around, and retrieving the Address from a shared repository instead?

I haven't tried that yet. Fetching this data again from API would resolve my issues, but I was looking for a solution that resolves it without API call

FWIW, a repository object can include a cache (disk and/or memory).

Thanks @ianhanniballake
If someone would look for a solution to this issue for Compose Multiplatform:
@OptIn(ExperimentalEncodingApi::class)
val AddressType = object : NavType<Address?>(isNullableAllowed = true) {
    override fun get(bundle: Bundle, key: String): Address? {
        return bundle.getString(key)?.takeIf { it != "null" }
            ?.let { Json.decodeFromString(Base64.UrlSafe.decode(it).decodeToString()) }
    }

    override fun parseValue(value: String): Address? {
        return if (value == "null") null else Json.decodeFromString(Base64.UrlSafe.decode(value).decodeToString())
    }

    override fun serializeAsValue(value: Address?): String {
        return Base64.UrlSafe.encode(Json.encodeToString(value).encodeToByteArray())
    }

    override fun put(bundle: Bundle, key: String, value: Address?) {
        bundle.putString(key, Base64.UrlSafe.encode(Json.encodeToString(value).encodeToByteArray()))
    }
}


As explained in the Providing custom types documentation, you need to Uri.encode your Json.encodeToString(value) in serializeAsValue:
override fun serializeAsValue(value: SearchParameters): String {
    // Serialized values must always be Uri encoded
    return Uri.encode(Json.encodeToString(value))
}

